# How to intercept calls to id<protocol> objects?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I am linking my code against framework which returns to my app objects of type `id<protocol>`. However, I don't know what class they are.
Is there a way that I can intercept messages sent to those objects in my program, maybe selectively too, for instance, I want to intercept message `A` but not message `B`.
I considered using `method_exchangeImplementations` but it doesn't seem helpful to me, since it requires knowing the class and that I don't know.

Comment: Can you wrap the objects that are being returned to you in your own class that also implements the protocol?

Comment: This is how I currently do it, but it's not perfect. objective id<T1> can return object id<T2> which can return object id<T3>. And I also want to intercept id<T3> as well for instance; and with this propose solution, I have to intercept all creation methods and return custom objects then. Was wondering if there is something cleaner.

Comment: You could try to use this aspect library using the instead option which could allow you to intercept the calls https://github.com/steipete/Aspects

Comment: In the simulator, you can use `mach_override` with `objc_msgSend` perhaps. See the example outlined in https://github.com/richardjrossiii/mach_override_example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id<protocol>` means, quite literally, **there is nothing about this object that is guaranteed other than that it responds to the `@required` methods in *protocol***.

Relying on customized behavior on the `id` part of the equation is guaranteed to yield a fragile, difficult to maintain, codebase.   Every time the framework revs, you're going to have to do a fully qualification pass of both success and failure cases to make sure your interpretation of that framework's behavior still remains correct.   And if you don't have the source to said framework, then you're in for a whole bunch of black box sleuthing.

So, don't do that.  Unless you're writing a test harness or doing some advanced debugging.  It can be very useful.

If you want to go there, @simple_code mentioned the Aspects library and that is a great place to start.   Since you don't know the type of what you're going to receive, you're probably going to need to do some type disambiguation using `isKindOfClass:` but, again, going down that path is exposing you to more and more dependence that the framework's implementation details (not just the interface) don't change.